# JxBrowser 6 hangs in osx el capitan

Tags: java, javafx, chromium, jxbrowser

I am evaluating JxBrowser 6.4 as the browser engine for our application. We need our software to work on Window as well as OSX. When I try to run the javafx example for JxBrowser 6, it just hangs (no window appears). There're no exception and the application just hangs without any UI.

Here's the code (copy-pasted from the jxbrowser docs):

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JfxView extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(browserView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        browser.loadHTML("<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The last few logs are as follows:

```
JxBrowser license valid.
08:10:02 INFO: OS name: Mac OS X
08:10:02 INFO: JRE version: 1.8.0_65 64-bit
08:10:02 INFO: JxBrowser version: 6.4
08:10:02 INFO: JxBrowser type: HEAVYWEIGHT
08:10:02 INFO: Starting IPC...
08:10:02 INFO: Starting IPC Server...
08:10:02 INFO: Starting socket server
08:10:02 INFO: Starting socket server at port 1101...
08:10:02 INFO: Starting IPC Process...
```

The swing example works fine and the same code runs perfectly fine on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the example from JxBrowser documentation [page](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013071-using-jxbrowser-in-javafx) that describes how to use JxBrowser in JavaFX app. Here's example:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserCore;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.Environment;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to embed Browser instance into JavaFX application.
 */
public class JavaFXSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        // On Mac OS X Chromium engine must be initialized in non-UI thread.
        if (Environment.isMac()) {
            BrowserCore.initialize();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(view), 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```